# String.Contains() for Chinese Characters

Tags: c#, string, contains

I have two strings containing chinese characters and I want to see if the first string contains the second string. However, just using String.Contains() does not work. Does anyone know an alternative method?

```
string c1 = " 未送出的礼物  dons non-donnés  ";
string c2 = " 未送出的礼物  ";
if(c1.Contains(c2))
{
   //this never happens but it should
}
```

Comment: It should enter the if statement but it does not for whatever reason.

Comment: I tested and `c1.Contains(c2);` returns true, so I vote to close as "not reproducable".

Comment: it works, on my machine. c1 contains c2

Comment: Would there be a reason it wouldn't work on my machine? Literally the exact code I'm using...

Comment: The two strings are probably different at the Unicode codepoint level. Have you tried Unicode normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first variable is in chinese simplified while the other is in chinese traditional. While they look the same when I was stepping through my code, they are actually different and hence why the if statement never got stepped into.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`String.Normalize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method on the strings before calling `String.Contains()`:

```
string c1 = string.Normalize(" 未送出的礼物  dons non-donnés  ");
string c2 = string.Normalize(" 未送出的礼物  ");
if(c1.Contains(c2))
{
  //...
}
```